# Nuget.Server 404 on package Push

Tags: nuget

I have setup NuGet.Server 3.3+ on Windows 10 IIS

[Working][1]

[I can browse already inited packages on the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYDG1.png)

When I try and push a known working package to my server

```
nuget push webgrease.1.6.0.nupkg -Source http://localhost/NuGetSrv/nuget
```

I get

[I get 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvw3o.png)

In fiddler the package is sent it looks to be a security issue on the server when it goes to write the file

I have use not network service / classic app pool and also tried admin account for the app pool

Also tried local c:\somedir and a \server\share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem :/

If you can get packages but not add

Make sure you have the application pool set to ***Integrated*** and not Classic and your network share will work for pushing packages

Comment: That Worked Straight up :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Azure, @HoopSnake's answer still apply, but its worderd differently.

In the App Service => Application Settings => **Managed Pipeline Version** set this to *Integrated*.

Atleast, that's what fixed it for me